# porto theme - critical.css file is not evaluated

Tags: magento2.3, css, pagespeed, porto-theme, criticalpathcss

Magento 2.3.6. We are trying to increase the pagespeed of the porto magento theme and we got recommendations to use critical css path.

We followed up the instructions for critical css path:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html

In short, we did this:

- `echo '.test {}' > app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/css/critical.css`
- `bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 1`
- `bin/magento c:f`
- `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --jobs 4 en_US en_GB`
- `bin/magento c:c; bin/magento c:f`

We tried to add a critical.css file in porto main theme:

```
$ cat app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/css/critical.css
.test {}
```

Instead of the expected `.test {}` (regardless of the critical.css content, happens even with a critical-css-generated content) in the html's `<style> </style>`, we get a different content than the expected one.

This makes me think the porto theme has a different filePath for critical.css?

Magento 2 docs recommend placing it as `web/css/critical.css`

Where should we place the critical.css file for porto theme? Or does it required some extra configuration to be applied?

Thanks

Comment: I expect you saw this in the docs "CSS critical path configuration is located on the Stores > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer tab. However, the Developer tab is hidden in production mode. Once in production mode, CSS critical path can only be enabled using the CLI."

Comment: Yes, we have used the cli command to enable the critical css path.

Comment: Hi Savvas, you solved it ?

Comment: @vivex unfortunately not, AFAIR the company moved to PWA and other frontend solutions